# How should I solve this circular dependency

Tags: java, javafx, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, afterburner.fx

```
I use a dependency injection framework called afterburner.fx btw.

Basically, I have View1, which contains a button to go to View2, so View1 depends on View2. 
But View2 has a back button, so it on View1. As a result, my programs output looks like this:

    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.String.startsWith(String.java:1495)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.isBuiltinStreamHandler(URL.java:1675)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.isBuiltinStreamHandler(URL.java:1670)
    at java.base/java.net.URLStreamHandler.setURL(URLStreamHandler.java:523)
    at java.base/java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(URLStreamHandler.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.parseURL(Handler.java:67)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:701)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:568)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1216)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:1205)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:294)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findResourceOnClassPath(BuiltinClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findResource(BuiltinClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1401)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1737)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:2728)
    at com.airhacks.afterburner.configuration.Configurator.getProperties(Configurator.java:74)
    at com.airhacks.afterburner.configuration.Configurator.getProperty(Configurator.java:103)
loop:
    at com.airhacks.afterburner.injection.Injector.injectMembers(Injector.java:140)
    at com.airhacks.afterburner.injection.Injector.injectMembers(Injector.java:129)
    at com.airhacks.afterburner.injection.Injector.injectAndInitialize(Injector.java:122)
    at com.airhacks.afterburner.injection.Injector.instantiateModelOrService(Injector.java:111)
loop x 200
```

How should I solve this? I thought of editing the source code of afterburner.fx to instantiate register classes first, THEN inject their fields.

Answer (score 0):

I made a class that contains a `HashMap<Class<? extends View>,<View>>`, and did `hashMap.put(this.getClass(), this)` in View1, and `View1 view1 = hashMap.get(View1.class);` in View2